# WPF UserControl issue - VisibilityChanged event is called but the UIElements of ControlTemplate is still null

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I need to change WPF comboBox background on Windows 10. One solution to handle this issue is to modify the border.Background from control template.

The code snippet is like the following

```
    private void ChangeBackground(object sender)
    {
        var osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;
        // Version > Windows 7 (6.1) ?
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx
        if (osInfo.Version.Major < 6 || osInfo.Version.Minor < 2) return;

        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox == null) return;
        var comboBoxTemplate = comboBox.Template;
        if (comboBoxTemplate == null) return;
        var toggleButton = comboBoxTemplate.FindName("toggleButton", comboBox) as ToggleButton;
        if (toggleButton == null) return;
        var toggleButtonTemplate = toggleButton.Template;
        var border = toggleButtonTemplate.FindName("templateRoot", toggleButton) as Border;
        if (border == null) return;

        // IsEnable?
        border.Background = (((ComboBox)(sender)).IsEnabled == false)
            ? (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFF0F0F0"))
            : comboBox.Background;
    }
```

But the toggleButton is null while the VisibilityChanged event is called.
Now I work around by timer. It works fine but dirty.

Might anyone provide any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: I hardly recommend to get familiar with the MVVM pattern and the using of IValueConverter. Problems like this aren't problems anymore when you use the correct patterns instead of code behind workarounds.

Comment: Actually I use the MVVM pattern to code my program. I don't know how to use IValueConverter to solve this issue. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get a reference to the `ToggleButton` when the `ComboBox` is collapsed because it is then removed from the visual tree so there is no `ToggleButton` to get a reference to.

The correct way of solving this would be to override the control template of the `ComboBox`/`ToggleButton` in XAML.

You can right-click on the `ComboBox` element in design mode in Visual Studio and select the "Edit template" option and then the "Edit a copy..." option to copy the default template into your XAML markup and then modify it as per your requirements. This is a way better solution than using a timer...Please refer to the following link for more information about this.

**Changing the background colour of a ComboBox in WPF on Windows 8:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/

Comment: Thanks mm8, You provide a good explain about the ToggleButton behavior. But I don't want to override the control template of the ComboBox. I use the UserControl to keep the code for easy maintenance.

Comment: Then you won't be able to change the background of a collapsed ComboBox. It is as simple as that.